# Make two references to the same React element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

does anyone know how to deal with the following situation in react: I use a custom hook that references an element, this works fine. But I need to use another custom hook that has to reference that same element. here the code.

```
function AppComponent(){
  const element= useHookrefone()
  const hover= useHookHoverref()

  return (
          <div ref={element}>hello</div>
         )

}
```

the second hook must refer to the div, but since there is already one for this last hook, how can it be assigned?

Comment: Pass element into the hover hook?

Comment: the second hook works like this ```<DIV ref={hover}>text</DIV>```